# Java Memory Visibility In Constructors

Tags: java, memory, concurrency

For the following simplified class:

```
public class MutableInteger {
    private int value;
    public MutableInteger(int initial) {
        synchronized(this) { // is this necessary for memory visibility?
            this.value = initial;
        }
    }
    public synchronized int get() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public synchronized void increment() {
        this.value++;
    }
    ...
}
```

I guess the general question is for mutable variables guarded by synchronization is it necessary to synchronize when setting the initial value in the constructor?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't see any way two threads could be in the same instance while it is being constructed so I would say no.  If value was static perhaps, but then you would need to synchronize on the class object and not the this reference.

Comment: @biziclop I'm just trying to make sure all my code is correct with respect to thread-safety and to better understand the java memory model.

Comment: @nikdeapen You should then simply declare your field `volatile` and forget about synchronization. At least in this example. `volatile` guarantees visibility of all write operations to the field.

Comment: @Pace I think the problem here is with visibility and the danger of stale values in other threads. Is synchronization in the constructor required to **ensure** visibility to other threads?

Comment: @RAnders00 What visibility. Until the constructor returns, no one, not even the calling method, has access to the object.

Comment: @biziclop volatile would not work in most situations and would not work in this example because of the increment operation.

Comment: @Andreas It is possible that threads other than the value-setting thread are seelng "stale" values, meaning that the update to a variable may not get pushed to other threads. Is synchronization required here to prevent stale values or not?

Comment: @nikdeapen You're right, I expanded on it in my answer.

Comment: @RAnders00 -- even if only one thread can be in the constructor that thread can give the reference to another thread but there is no guarantee that the value would be visible to the other thread (because of cpu caching)

Comment: @biziclop I see your point and agree you are correct.

Comment: @Andreas That's true but that doesn't mean visibility isn't a problem. There is no guarantee that other threads, when they receive a reference to the newly constructed object, will see it fully constructed.

Comment: @biziclop If that's true, then many (all?) the synchronized classes in the Java Runtime Library are flawed, e.g. `StringBuffer` and `Vector`. Neither has any synchronize in the constructor, but all other methods are synchronized, and they are supposed to be correctly synchronized.

Comment: @Andreas The specification is quite clear on this subject, However if you hand these objects to other threads in a thread-safe manner (by assigning them to a `final` field for example), it is guaranteed that you will see a version that is up-to-date as of the time of the hand-off.

Comment: @biziclop Where in the specification is it made clear that an un-synchronized assignment to a non-final field in the constructor may not be visible to a *synchronized* method call from another thread?

Comment: @Andreas That the method call is `synchronized` is irrelevant, synchronization only establishes a happens-before relationship between blocks that lock on the same monitor. The constructor doesn't do that by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, without the `synchronized` block in the constructor there is no visibility guarantee for non-final fields, as can be seen in [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).

However in practice I would rather use `volatile` fields or the `Atomic*` classes in situations like this.

**Update:** It is also important to mention here that in order for your program to be `correctly synchronized` (as defined by the JLS), you will need to publish the reference to your object in a safe manner. The cited example doesn't do that, hence why you may see the wrong value in non-final fields. But if you publish the object reference correctly (i.e. by assigning it to a `final` field of another object, or by creating it before calling `Thread.start()`), it is guaranteed that your object will be seen at least as up-to-date as the time of publishing, therefore making the `synchronized` block in the constructor unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.   I would definitely use the atomic classes in this case but this only works in simple cases.

Comment: If I didn't see that in the Java spec with my own eyes, I'd call you a liar.  OK, time to go post about this on The Daily WTF.

Comment: @Powerlord I think most modern VMs do create a memory barrier at the end of a constructor, but not having it guaranteed does indeed look weird. However having one rule for a constructor and another for other writes would probably be even more confusing.

Comment: That is not a valid example, because the accessing method (`reader()`) is not synchronized, while all access methods in this question are synchronized. If you look at the source for `StringBuffer` and `Vector`, both synchronized classes, neither has any synchronization in the constructor, but all methods are synchronized. Are you postulating that those classes don't work right? --- The synchronization done by `get()` and `increment()` establish happens-before boundaries, guaranteeing that all actions in the constructor happens-before these methods.

Comment: @Andreas There is an ellipsis in the OP's code (I would've agreed with what you're saying if that weren't the case).

Comment: @Andreas [Here are the rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4). I can't see a happens-before edge that automatically leads from the end of the constructor to the first `synchronized` block. Can you?

Comment: @biziclop Unfortunately, I cannot find a rule to contradict you, but it means that e.g. `java.util.Vector`, whose constructor assigns the non-final field `elementData`, may cause NPE in `add()` because that assignment may not have happened yet. As such, the conclusion from your statement is that `Vector` is not the thread-safe class it claims to be.

Comment: @Andreas No, `Vector` is perfectly thread-safe so long as the rest of your code is thread-safe too. Only if you're doing stupid things with it, then it isn't safe, but that isn't a problem. I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: @biziclop java.util.Vector add() internally calls insertElementAt and that method is synchronized on the Vector's monitor.  So even though add() is not synchronized, because add() only calls insertElementAt, add() effectively is synchronized as well.  Java Concurrency in Practice's chapter 4 Composing Objects calls this synchronization policy the java monitor pattern.

Comment: @buzz3791 That is true but it is not the problem here. The question is if there is a synchronisation edge leading from the end of the constructor to the beginning of `add()` (or `insertElementAt()`). And if you don't publish the reference to your newly created `Vector` safely, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Though you've accepted an answer, let me add my two cents.
Based on what I've read, synchronization or making the field volatile would not grantee the following visibility.

A thread T1 may see a not-null value for `this`, but unless you've made the field `value` final, there's a good chance of thread T1 seeing the default value of `value`.

The value could be a volatile or been accessed within synchronized blocks (monitor acquire and release), either way provided that the correct execution order was followed, there's happens-before edge from the write to the read of `value`. There's no argument on that. 
But it's not the happens before edge that we have to consider here, but the correct publication of the object itself(MutableInteger). 
Creating an object is twofold where the JVM first allocates a heap space and then start initializing fields. A thread may see a not-null reference of an object but an uninitialized field of that as long as the said field is not final (Assuming reference has been correctly published).